# Marquee doesn't work when text is set after some time

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I am trying to enable marquee effect on a text view which is populated the data from the server but the marquee doesnt take effect. I could simulate it with postDelayed and noticed that if the text is set right after view is inflated then it is fine, but if the view is inflated and the text is set afterwards then it doesnt work.

activity_marquee_test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/marqueeTest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:singleLine="true"
    />
    
</FrameLayout>
```

MarqueeTestActivity.kt:

```
class MarqueeTestActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_marquee_test)
        val marqueeTest = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.marqueeTest)

        // setting it here works fine
        marqueeTest.text =
                "Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!"
        marqueeTest.isSelected = true

        Handler().postDelayed({
            // setting it here doesn't work - it cuts the text and add '...' at the end.
            marqueeTest.text =
                "Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!"
            marqueeTest.isSelected = true
        }, 2000)

    }
}
```

theme is set to `@style/Theme.AppCompat`

any ideas how to make it work? I am hopeless and already am considering writing my custom widget...

Comment: What do you mean with it doesn't work? The text is not updating, but the effect still works? Or no text is shown at all?

Comment: the text is shown but it doesnt move and it has ... at the end

Comment: After setText and before isSelected in postDelayed - can your try there:
testing.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
testing.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
testing.setSingleLine(true); I know you set it in XML but who knows

Comment: Also can it be related to your layout? Could you experimentally remove all other views in this layout and check if the problem still exists?

Comment: I noticed that if I launch the MarqueeTestActivity directly then it animates correctly. If I launch it from the other activity (as a response to a click event) then it gets truncated ad the end and does not animate.

Answer (score 0):

your code is mistake and Handler is deprecated.
use this below code is working properly.

```
val marqueeTest = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.marqueeTest)
    
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
       
       marqueeTest.text =
                    "Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World!"
            }, 2000)
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/marqueeTest"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_gravity="center"
                 android:ellipsize="end"
                 android:singleLine="true"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Handler() vs Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) is not a problem here

actually when i put that activity in a separate project it works fine but when it is in my other project it doesnt work

Comment: i do not understand your questions.

Comment: it turn out that it must be something else - when i use that code in a plain project it works - when i use it another bigger project it doesnt. In the project where it wokrs it deosnt matter whether I use Handler() or Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()). And Handler() when used on main thread it will use mainLooper anyway.

Comment: @RadekJ the code which I sent you do works with me,.... but still I'll tell you to elaborate a little about the problem or what you really need?...AS in elaborate with some screenshot or something

Comment: I am trying to create a minimum sample code which reproduces the problem but no luck so far...